# How do you derive the formula for the expected value of a random variable given an event?

Tags: probability, definition, conditional-expectation, expected-value

I've been given two formulas:

> **Discrete Case:** $$\mathbb{E}(X|Y=y)=\sum_{x\in S_{X}} xp_{X|Y}(x|y)$$

and

> **Continuous Case:** $$\mathbb{E}(X|Y=y) = \int_{x \in S_{X}}xf_{X|Y}(x|y)$$

where $S_X$ is the domain for variation for $X$ in both cases.

> Just based on this, is it possible to deduce the expectation of
>   $\mathbb{E}(X|A)$ for a continuous random variable $X$ and an event
>   $A$?

**I have not been given any other definitions and I need to find this for a question.**

I was thinking of instead using an indicator random variable $$\mathbb{1}_A = \begin{cases} 1 \quad \text{If A occurs} \\ 0 \quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

and then instead trying to find the expectation $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathbb{1}_{A}=1)$. But I'm not sure how to find this since $X$ is continuous but $\mathbb{1}_{A}$ is discrete.

---

Specifically, I'm trying to find $E(X_1| X_1\le\frac{1}{2}, X_2 \le \frac{1}{2})$ and $E(X_2| X_1\le\frac{1}{2}, X_2 \le \frac{1}{2})$ where $X_1 \sim U(0,1)$ and $X_2|X_1 \sim U(0,X_1)$. I believe I need to know the first the definition I have asked about above.

Comment: @Thomas Yes indeed I am thinking of that formula. 
I have seen something similar.

I wanted to know if it is possible to see how it comes from the definitions above.

Comment: @Thomas Could you confirm what "Y" is in your comment?

Comment: @Thomas Actually, I think the formula I've seen is more like $E[X|A] = \frac{E[X\mathbb{1}_A]}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$. Is that the same as yours?

Comment: In the case I have, is actually $A = \{ X \le \frac{1}{2} \}$, sorry that wasn't clear in the question, (the example at the very end)

Comment: ( I deleted my comments since I was answering indeed to a different question )

Comment: Your completely general question is significantly more complicated than your special case, unfortunately. It is a lot simpler if A is given as a preimage of the variables in question in the first place.

Comment: @Ian Ohh I see. Yes I think i was noticing that when I was trying to derive it. Is there an easier result for $ E(\mathbf{X} | f(\mathbf{X}) \in A) $? If so, would you happen to know how I could determine what it is?

Answer (score 1):

I am trying just to answer to the final problem avoiding too many general reasonings.

We have $X_1,X_2$ r.v. with joint p.d.f. $p(x_1,x_2)$. If we have $I \subset \mathbf{R}^2$, $A=\{ (X_1,X_2) \in I\}$ and $f(x_1,x_2)$ a scalar function than:

> $E[f(X_1,X_2)|A]=E[f(X_1,X_2)1_A]/P(A)=\int_I p(x_1,x_2)f(x_1,x_2)dx_1dx_2/P(A) [1]$

, where the first step is just by definition of conditional measure and the second is simply the computation of the integral using the joint density.

In our case we first find $I$. Since $X_2 \le X_1$ we have that when $X_1\le1/2$ also $X_2\le1/2$, so that $A=\{X_1 \le 1/2\}$ and $I=\{(x_1,x_2)|x_1  \le 1/2\}$.

Now for the exercise:

> $p(x_1,x_2)=p(x_1)p(x_2|x_1)=1_{[0,1]}(x_1)1_{[0,x_1]}(x_2)/x_1 [2]$

where $1_A$ are indicator functions.

We have than $p(A)=1/2$ and for example, applying [1] and [2] to $f(x_1,x_2)=x_2$, I find:

$E[X_2|A]=2\int_0^{1/2}dx_1\int_0^{1}dx_2 1_{[0,1]}(x_1)1_{[0,x_1]}(x_2)x_2/x_1=1/8$